# How to change the first segment of a URL and maintain the rest of the segments in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have pages in my site where the url segment are automatically filled depending on the values of the fields in the page.

And example url is:

http://example.com/students/uk/nikki/86/18-25

where nikki/86/18-25 are dynamic segments.

What I was to do is to simple make an htaccess redirect rule where if a user will go to:

http://example.com/students/uk/nikki/86/18-25

they will automatically be redirected to:

http://example.com/student/uk/nikki/86/18-25

So it's just to make the students segment to student. And since the nikki/86/18-25 segments changes per page, they would be retained during the redirect.

Is this possible in htaccess?

Comment: You seem to have a typo, the `FROM` and `TO` urls are the same at the moment. :)

Comment: No they're not. As I said from /students to /student

Comment: Ha I missed the `s`, thanks for clarifying, will post a solution soon. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the `.htaccess` file in your web document root folder (often `public_html` or `htdocs`):

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^students/uk/([^/]+) student/uk/$1 [L,R,DPI]
```

Once you are satisfied that the redirect works, you can change the `R` to `R=301` to make it permanent.
This assumes that mod_rewrite is **both** installed **and** activated for htaccess files. 
If you are not sure, to check if mod_rewrite is installed, look at the list of installed modules in the output of `phpinfo();`
By default, mod_rewrite is not enabled for htaccess files. If you are managing your own server, open `httpd.conf`
and make sure that the webroot directory block contains one of these lines: `AllowOverride FileInfo` or `AllowOverride All`

Comment: Hi thanks for this. I am still having a problem though. It's redirecting but to this url /home/students/public_html/student/uk/nikki/86/18-25. Is there something that I need to check to get rid of /home/students/public_html url segments?

Comment: Edited the answer, please try the new version. :)

Comment: Still no luck. :( Now it only goes to http://example.com/home/students/public_html/student/uk/nikki. The rest of the segments disappeared. My .htaccess file is inside public_html directory.